# _tOwned become 0 when an address is included in reward in safemoon contract

Tags: erc-20

in the safemoon reflection token when an address is included in reward the _tOwned of the address become 0.

```
        require(_isExcluded[account], "Account is already included");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_excluded[i] == account) {
                _excluded[i] = _excluded[_excluded.length - 1];
               **_tOwned[account] = 0;**
                _isExcluded[account] = false;
                _excluded.pop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

but it when an address is excluded from reward then the _tOwned of the account is

`_tOwned[account] = tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);`

what if an excluded account have 10 tokens so the _tOwned will be 10. and then the account is included in rewards the _tOwned will become 0 and the account will lose the 10 tokens it had